# Symfony2 - define collection type form as a service

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony2-forms

I would like to use a service in my form `PRE_SET_DATA` event listener. Now this form is embedded into another form type as `CollectionType`.

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    private $entitymanager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entitymanager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entitymanager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...     

        // Add listeners
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        ...

        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

    ...
}
```

To inject entity manager service I defined form type as a service:

```
services:
    form_type_child:
        class: IndexBundle\Form\Type\ChildType
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

And now I have to use this form as a `CollectionType`:

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
             ->add('child', CollectionType::class, array(
                'type' => ChildType::class,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false
             ))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

Now I get this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   IndexBundle\Form\Type\ChildType::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\trainingexperience_symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php
>   on line 90 and defined

Any ideas how can I pass entity manager in `CollectionType` embedded form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tag the service as a form:

```
services:
    form_type_child:
        class: IndexBundle\Form\Type\ChildType
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Hope this help